# Find max of list using higher order function

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use filter (though I can also use map and/or foldr) to find the max element of a list.

I tried filtering out every number less than max but it refuses to accept max as a filter argument.

Here's my code:

```
 max' :: Ord a => [a] -> a
 max' xs = filter (< max) xs
```

Here's the error I get:

```
* Couldn't match type `a' with `a0 -> a0 -> a0'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      max' :: forall a. Ord a => [a] -> a
    at Prog8.hs:50:1-25
  Expected type: [a0 -> a0 -> a0]
    Actual type: [a]
* In the second argument of `filter', namely `xs'
  In the expression: filter (< max) xs
  In an equation for max': max' xs = filter (< max) xs
* Relevant bindings include
    xs :: [a] (bound at Prog8.hs:51:6)
    max' :: [a] -> a (bound at Prog8.hs:51:1)
```

Is there a way to write max' in a simple filter function (or maybe combine it with map or foldr)?

Comment: It's easy enough to implement `max` as a fold. (I think any recursive function on a list can be done as a fold.) But you definitely can't do it with just `map` and/or `filter`. (Well I don't see how, someone might prove me wrong though :) )

Comment: Could I do it with foldr? I'm trying to stick with foldr, map, and filter.

Comment: Yes, you certainly can. Your accumulator is just the maximum "so far". You probably want `foldr1` rather than `foldr` (it crashes on an empty list, but so does `max`).

Comment: Just realised the function that finds the max value of a list is actually `maximum` (`max` takes 2 plain values and returns the greater)

Comment: With the type signature you have, the only sensible thing that `max' []` can return is ⊥. If you can restructure your calling code so that this can have either `Ord a => NonEmpty a -> a` or `Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a` instead, then ⊥ can be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty list has no maximum element, so you can't write a total function with the type you've provided. A more sensible one is

```
maximum' :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
```

The easy way to do this is with `foldl'`:

```
maximum' = foldl' gom Nothing where
  gom Nothing new = Just new
  gom (Just old) new
    | old < new = Just new
    | otherwise = Just old
```

But you want `foldr`. Since `foldl'` is actually defined in terms of `foldr`, this is easy!

```
foldl' f b0 xs = foldr gof id xs b0
  where
    gof x r b = b `seq` r (f b x)
```

Inlining,

```
maximum' xs = foldr gob id xs Nothing
  where
    --gob new r b = b `seq` r (gom b new)
    gob new r b = seq b $ r $
      case b of
        Nothing -> Just new
        Just old
          | old < new -> Just new
          | otherwise -> Just old
```

Doing a little manual strictness analysis, this simplifies to

```
maximum' xs = foldr gob id xs Nothing
  where
    gob new r b = r $!
      case b of
        Nothing -> Just new
        Just old
          | old < new -> Just new
          | otherwise -> Just old
```

---

A small caution: if this is homework and you turn in my solution, your teacher will likely become suspicious. There's a much simpler way that's also much less efficient, but I'll let you search for it.

Answer (score -1):

So first off, as you discovered, what you wanted is:

```
max' :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
max' xs = filter (< maximum xs) xs
```

If you are absolutely dedicated to pointfree style for some reason, and want to write using only higher-order functions, this will also work:

```
max' :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
max' = flip filter <*> ((>) <$> maximum)
```

don't do that though, it's awful. Just repeat the argument twice.

Comment: This doesn't typecheck.

Comment: Sorry, I was taking the type from the question, when what the questioner asked for obviously requires a different type.

Fixed.

Comment: I doubt that was what they really intended.

Comment: I found this super helpful, not sure why it was down-voted.

Comment: I've been having a downvote kind of day on here; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/55957477/107331 . In this case, I answered the question I thought you were asking "find all elements less than the maximum", not the question you did ask.

Comment: @Francis [*"Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is especially useful, vote it up!"*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) "Awarded at: 15 reputation"

Comment: @DanielMartin "to filter them *out*" probably means `\xs -> filter (not . (< maximum xs)) xs  =  \xs -> filter (maximum xs <=) xs  =  filter =<< ((<=) . maximum)`. :)