# Get Stack to pass test suite name as part of --test-arguments

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

It's possible, with cabal, to set up a continuous build that records test successes/failures in a format many CI systems will accept with a command like:

```
cabal test '--test-option=--jxml=test-results/$test-suite.xml'
```

The important part here is that `$test-suite` is replaced with the name of the test, so that different tests put their results into different files.

When I use stack, all tests get literally the option `--jxml=test-results/$test-suite.xml` passed to them, so the end result is that the tests overwrite each others' results.

Is there any way to run all my tests with `stack` so that I can tell each test suite a different place to write their results?

I'd even accept some stack command that parsed the cabal file for me and told me what test suites there are, because then I could script a loop in bash calling each test one at a time.

Comment: typo `s/slack/stack/`

Comment: Just the one spot, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd even accept some stack command that parsed the cabal file for me and told me what test suites there are, because then I could script a loop in bash calling each test one at a time.

If you're willing to stoop to that, `stack ide targets` will return a list of targets, from which you can do some bashing to get the list of test suites. Something like this:

```sh
stack ide targets 2>&1 |
  while IFS=: read pkg type suite; do
    [[ $type = test ]] && stack test ":$suite" --test-arguments="--jxml=test-results/$suite.xml"
  done
```

Answer (score -1):

`stack test --test-arguments="--jxml=test-results/$test-suite.xml"`

Comment: When I do that, the effect is that all my tests write to the same file, called `test-results/$test-suite.xml`.

Comment: Well, actually, using that syntax they all write to `test-results/-suite.xml`, because bash, but if I single-quote that bit you've got double-quoted I get all the tests writing to `test-results/$test-suite.xml`.

Also, I mentioned this in my question.

Comment: something like that `XX="--jxml=test-results/$test-suite.xml" YY="stack test --test-arguments=$XX"  $YY`. It would be wise to rename `test-suite`. [See](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Rules_for_Naming_variable_name)

Comment: But the *ACTUAL POINT*, in any case is that unlike cabal (which will substitute `$test-suite` for the test name when it runs each test), stack will do no such substitution. So I still get all of the tests writing to the same file, and overwriting each other's results